# grayscale picture in list

Tags: python, list, grayscale

i'm tring to make a list with grayscales from pictures. starting at the left top and ending in the bottom right. every line as should be a sublist. i want to export it to excel.

```
from PIL import Image





foto_pad = str(input("pad naar de foto? \n"))
foto = Image.open(foto_pad).convert('1')

bewerkte_foto = foto.save("bewerking_" + foto_pad, quality=1)
bewerkte_foto_breedte, bewerkte_foto_hoogte = (Image.open("bewerking_"+foto_pad).convert('L')).size
bewerkte_foto_data = list(foto.getdata())

bewerkte_foto_data = [(Image.open("bewerking_" + foto_pad).convert("L")).getdata()]
bewerkte_foto_data = [bewerkte_foto_data[offset:offset+bewerkte_foto_breedte] for offset in range(0, bewerkte_foto_breedte*bewerkte_foto_hoogte, bewerkte_foto_breedte)]

for rij in bewerkte_foto_data:
    for waarde in rij:
        print(" ".join("{:2}".format(waarde)))
```

the outcome should be like this: [[255,120,1,...],[120,240,150,...],[...]]

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the job with OpenCV and pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
gray_list = [[str(pixel) for pixel in row] for row in img]
df = pd.DataFrame(gray_list)
df.to_excel('grayscale.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```